# How to stop adding ui-page-theme-a class to DOM element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying with jQuery mobile to stop adding its default classes to DOM elements. The class `ui-page-theme-a` may be actual problem, because this one overriding the default CSS of the `<a>` tag and this one problem broke the whole page layout.

Even adding `data-role="none"` to `<a />` is not getting me ride out of this

I also tried global configuration added on this url https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html but also this doesn't helped me.

I don't know what I am missing,

I am using jQuery mobile **1.4.5**.

The *jquery mobile* is wrapping all of my website content into a div which has following classes on initialization:

```
ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active
```

The class `ui-page-theme-a` is bothering me as it's overriding my default CSS for `<a />` tag. How I can get rid out of this one? May be stopping `ui-page-theme-a` this one class solve my question.

Comment: you can stop the `element`'s enhancement or override the CSS classes, so there are several ways, can you post your custom `a` CSS?

Comment: What styling settings are you trying to preserve? Are these settings you defined yourself?

Comment: @Shai I am using bootstrap but the jquery mobile CSS got priority over the bootstrap classes as bootstrap input design replaces by the jquery mobile as it adds its own classes to input elements and also hyperlinks

Comment: @deblocker I am using red color for `a` tag but the jquery mobile applies it's own styles as it got priority over classes.... so the fCSS is going to be changed with jquery mobile CSS

Comment: if you need to use bootstrap CSS then don't include the jQueryMobile CSS, add in your head a reference to the CSS without theme http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Comment: @deblocker thank you

Comment: Check Solution 2 in dup answer.

Comment: @Omar thanks, this one is the solution what I wanted.